# Python and OverflowError

Tags: python, decimal, overflow

I write a simple app in `python`. I post a part of my function:

```
1. from datetime import datetime
2. partialResult = (datetime(1970,2,2)-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
3. result = Decimal(pow(math.e, partialResult))
```

On the third line i get this error:

```
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Nevethereless i use `Decimal` i get the `OverflowError`.

So, how can i solve it?

Thank you

Comment: I edit my post sorry

Comment: Ok, with the changes you made, I get `2764800.0` for `partialResult`.  That is far too large a value to raise `math.e` to.  The result has `1200737` decimal digits!  I suggest re-thinking this.

Comment: It is possible to obtain, for example, only the first 6 or 10 digits?

Comment: From the documentation on `decimal`:  An Overflow signal gets generated if the exponent is greater than Emax.  Type `getcontext()`, and you can see what Emax is (999999, on my machine).

Comment: @jfsturtz It's never getting that far.  The call to `pow` is overflowing.

Comment: You want the first few digits, out of over a million, of e**2764800, is that correct?  It's difficult to see how this could be of any use, but there are probably some mathematical tricks you could use to scale the result before generating it.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: I used the calculator of my machine to check `pow(math.e, 2764800)`, where 2764800 is the value of `partialResult`: it is too large (my machine can not calculate it)

Comment: Ok i try to think anything about some math tricks, thank you to all.

Comment: Suppose you want to compute e**n, and you want to view the first several digits of the result when formatted in decimal (i.e., base 10).  Let m be the number of decimal digits you wish to eliminate.  So you want to compute (e\*\*n)/(10\*\*m).  This will preserve the initial digits while reducing the magnitude.  Now note that 10\*\*m = e\*\*log(10\*\*m) = e\*\*(m\*log(10)), where log is log base e (i.e. ln).  So we have (e\*\*n)/(10\*\*m) = (e\*\*n)/(e\*\*(m\*log(10))) = e\*\*(n-m\*log(10)).  You then just need to choose the desired value of m.